# How to import module from node_modules in angular

Tags: angular, import, node-modules

Maybe this is a stupid question, but anyway.

I have generated API services folder (generated with Swagger Codegen) as a package inside node_module. I have no idea why, but that's not the point of my question. When I try to import ApiModule in my AppModule and run app in console I have an error that ApiModule is undefined. And anything that I try to import from node modules have same result. If I move outside anywhere on my PC it work fine. So, my question is why it act like this and if there is any chance to do what I am trying.

```
// App Module in angular app
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    //ApiModule is located in node_modules/@dummy-package
    //If I move it outside the node_modules everything work fine
    ApiModule.forRoot(apiConfigFactory), // <==== ApiModule is undefined here
    HttpClientModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
DummyModule.isInit(); // <=== DummyModule is undefined as well


// Dummy module in /node_modules/@dummy-package/dummy.module.ts
@NgModule({})
export class DummyModule {
   static isInit() {
    console.warn('module is called');
  }
}
```

My expectation is to import module as from any other place and use it as all other modules in application. I've tried to create a dummy module and some experiments with imports and my conclusion is that any import from node modules folder that contain @NgModule() or @Injecatable() are not possible. But I have no explanation from that phenome.